# Creating boxplot using Matplotlib Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a boxplot using Matplotlib.

I had already did the data cleaning to 2018 to 2019. That's the data I required. I would like to plot x(years), y(median price) - boxplot with IQR range, Q1, Q3,max and min etc.

However I had an error that 'ValueError: Dimensions of labels and X must be compatible'

Answer (score 0):

What you have here `values_combined =[price2012, price2013,price2014]` is a list. 
A list of three `numpy` arrays. And I am not sure what is the size of the labels. Clearly there is a mismatch.

If you want o to combine those numpy arrays column wise or row wise you can try `np.c_` and `np.r_` functions.

Example:

```
>>> x = np.random.randint(0,10,size=3)
>>> y = np.random.randint(0,10,size=3)
>>> z = np.random.randint(0,10,size=3)
>>>
>>> [x,y,z]
[array([7, 6, 4]), array([5, 3, 1]), array([3, 5, 2])]
>>> np.c_[x,y,z]
array([[7, 5, 3],
       [6, 3, 5],
       [4, 1, 2]])
>>> np.r_[x,y,z]
array([7, 6, 4, 5, 3, 1, 3, 5, 2])
```

To solve your problem you have to ensure that the size/shape of `labels` and `data` matches. Hope that helps.